# Adding an interval between foreach loops

Tags: php, loops, foreach, timeout, wait

Very basically my code uses a foreach loop to execute a bit of code for each key in an array. The problem, however, is that this piece of code accesses an API that allows for only 50 requests per half minute. To prevent my requests from being blocked I'd like to add a timer to the loop that checks if at least one second has passed since this round has started before it can continue to the next one.
Any suggestions on how to implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way is to use `sleep`

```
sleep(10); // 10 seconds for example
```

for more information visit the PHP official document

[Delays the program execution for the given number of seconds](https://www.php.net/sleep)

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to use sleep() method inside the loop?

```
foreach($array as $key => $val){
    sleep(1); //parameter in seconds
    // keep rock'n rolling
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i found setTmeout most useful in this case, just make sure you have offset delay among iteration.

simple Angular example,

```
angular.forEach(someArray, index) {
    $timeout(function() {
            function1();
            function2(); 
    }, 100 * (index + 1) );
});
```